# Mac bash_profile commands not found when opening new terminal

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

My .bash_profile contains the following commands:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/shims:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi

eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

When I open a new terminal, I get the following errors:

```
Last login: Tue Mar 14 12:04:29 on ttys001
-bash: pyenv: command not found
-bash: pyenv: command not found
-bash: brew: command not found

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
```

But when I run these commands manually all is good. For example, when I source it like below, there are no errors. It only happens when ~.bash_profile is executed when I open a new terminal window.

```
source ~.bash_profile
```

What is going on?

Comment: When you say `source ~.bash_profile` you mean `source ~/.bash_profile`, right?

Comment: Anyhow -- are you sure it's really bash when you open a new window in the first place? If it's zsh, .bash_profile isn't the file that's running at all.

Comment: Is `/opt/homebrew/bin/` on your `PATH`? Note your last line works fine, as it doesn't rely on `PATH` lookup. What *does* your `PATH` look like?

Comment: One possibility: `eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shelling)` is supposed to be done *first*, and it is what sets up `PATH` to allow `pyenv` (and `brew` without a full path) to be found. Your second command doesn't fix anything, but works because the last line of the *first* command fixed your `PATH` *for* the second command.

Comment: A lot of this depends on where `pyenv` is supposed to come from. If it comes from `~/.pyenv/shims` that's a _very_ different answer than if it comes from a directory managed by Homebrew.